# Azure Resource Manager Template Deploy VM from Image Gallary

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager

I have been working at creating VM using Azure Resource Template but now want to create a specific VM from an Image in the gallery.

I am looking for the correct ARM syntax and steps needed for the following VM Image.

```
Get-AzureVMImage | where-Object {$_.ImageName -eq 'c6e0f177abd8496e934234bd27f46c5d__SharePoint-2016-Trial-9-13-2016'}
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple possibilities to create a virtual machine based on the given image.

1. Just create it in the Azure portal. It's possible to save or download the ARM Template that will be executed for reuse. To do this click the + in the portal and search for Sharepoint trial.
2. A bit harder is to create an ARM template yourself. Or [reuse an existing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/templates/) ARM template which creates a Virtual Machine and change it slightly. You have to pass the correct parameters for the Virtual Machine. The most important parameters are: The publisher, the Offer and the SKU.

When you follow step 1 these will be filled in for you already in the ARM template.
You can also get them with PowerShell:

- Get-AzurermVMImagePublisher -Location "West Europe"

  selected result: PublisherName = MicrosoftSharePoint
- Get-AzurermVMImageOffer -Location "West Europe" -PublisherName "MicrosoftSharePoint"

  result: Offer = MicrosoftSharePointServer
- Get-AzureRmVMImageSku -Location "West Europe" -Publisher “MicrosoftSharePoint” -Offer "MicrosoftSharePointServer" | Select Skus

  selected result: SKU = 2016